# Transform values of hash functions like MD5 into numbers

Tags: algorithms, hash

I have read about the hash function MD5. I found an online calculator which counts the value of MD5 for different data. But the MD5 function returns as result strings like `735b90b4568125ed6c3f678819b6e058`, so I can't apply any numerical operation to this value, e.g. `mod`.

How can I transform values like these into numbers?

Comment: I edited your question to make it less of a programming question (which are offtopic here). Note furthermore that hashes like MD5 are *not* appropriate in cryptographic settings (you tagged thus); check [crypto.SE] for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output `735b90b4568125ed6c3f678819b6e058` is just a [hexadecimal representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) of a 128-bit (in binary) number, which corresponds directly to an integer between $0$ and $2^{128}-1$.  Therefore, you can think of MD5 as returning a numeric value.  You should be able to make the conversion from hexadecimal  string to integer trivially using any programming language (if not, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) is the place to go to).

Comment: I edited the question; I think it's ontopic now, if very basic (but that's fair).